# How to make arrow visible for all the time on Slider banner

Tags: magento2, database, slider

[image]
I want to use fontawesome icon for arrow on my Slider banner for Next & Previous. What code I have to use for Magento 2.1.1? Can anyone please help
thanks me.

Comment: No I didn't integrate any third party extension. I want customize it.

Comment: It's an image for silder

Comment: I tried lot's of time but it's not working. I need help to fix it.

Comment: yes post your code whatever you have tried so that others can see where is the error

Comment: <div class="home-slider cms-static-main-slide slick-initialized slick-slider" data-slides-to-show="1" data-slides-to-scroll="1" data-fade="false" data-speed="400" data-autoplay="false" data-autoplay-speed="6000" data-dots="true" data-arrows="true" data-infinite="true" role="toolbar"><button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: inline-block;">Previous</button>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<div class="home-slider cms-static-main-slide slick-initialized slick-slider"
```

use

```
<div class="home-slider cms-static-main-slide"
```

(That is, remove the last two classes.)